# Help with ContextMenu with a multicolumn ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a listview which displays emails with the following layout:

```
email@address.com                            category  //This could be work etc
First line of the emails subject!
```

Using the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
 ........
 android:orientation="vertical">     
<LinearLayout       
 ........    
 android:orientation="horizontal">       
     <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
         android:layout_width="250dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#AFC7C7" android:textSize="9sp"/> 
     <TextView android:id="@+id/CATEGORY_CELL"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#34282C" android:textSize="9sp" android:gravity="right" />   
</LinearLayout>  
 <TextView android:id="@+id/SUBJECT_CELL"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

This all works fine, but when I put a ContextMenu on so I can allow long presses on certain emails, how would I go about retrieving the email address as to assign it a category?

On the database side my method takes 2 strings, 1 being the email address to assign a category and another string which is what to call the category.

I was wondering how you go about retrieving the email in the onContextItemSelected() method to allow for me to use it for assigning category's.

Sorry if this is a bad explanation, I have tried my best :)

Thanks,
Rhys

Comment: You want to know which row is pressed in ListView, i understand right ?

Comment: Not exactly the row is pressed, more how to access the data stored in the row, such as I would like to retrieve "email@address.com" to pass into a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It feels like I hacked my way to get the information but it seems to work :p

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
Object id = list.getItemAtPosition((int) info.id);
String row = id.toString();
String address = row.substring(row.indexOf("From=")+5, row.length()-1);
```